# Database Design - How to post 2 primary keys from different tables

Tags: database-design

and thanks for reading.

I'm making a DB for a puppy shop. I have a table for puppies and a table for **INDIVIDUAL** owners and Corporation Owners (Company owns puppy). A puppy can have one owner, owners can own more than one puppy. What's a good way to handle this situation?

1. Do I use 2 FKs in the puppy table, one of which is null if the puppy is owned by a individual owner or if the puppy is owned by a company.
2. Can you use null foreign keys in boyce-codd normal form.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:

```
Puppies
PuppyID
PuppyName
PuppyType
...

Owners
OwnerID
OwnerName
OwnerType   'I'=individual, 'C'=corporate 
....

PuppyOwners
OwnerID
PuppyID
```

Comment: What value your model brings over the one suggested in the question? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Piotr Czapla, why put 1 or 2 owner FKs in Puppies? Also, unless there is some really compelling reason (which the OP does not give) why complicate everything with two different Owners tables. Worst case add a 1 to 1 CorporateOwners and/or a 1 to 1 IndividualOwners table for (unique columns) and FK back to Owners.

Comment: The worst case scenario with 1-1 relations looks best but it is over complicated if one doesn't use an object relational mapping. Your suggestion works well with Entity Framework, Hibernate, Django. But not on the raw sql level. Merging to different entities People & Companies in one table makes the select statmets awful.

Comment: it isn't "people" and "Companies", it is "individual owners" and "corporate owners", which have much more overlap in their attributes.  People have birthdays and favorite colors, is that the type of data in this table? only OP knows. To me, owners (individual and corporate) have a name and an address, bank info, etc.  We're talking three tables here (and maybe two more) that is extremely simple even at a "raw" sql level.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Party Data Model](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014) as a template for your situation.

> Can you use null foreign keys in
>   boyce-codd normal form

No. 3NF, BCNF, 5NF, etc all deal exclusively with relations *without* nulls. That being so, it's a common practice (though highly questionable) to make some approximation or assumption about normal form by simply ignoring the possibility that nulls will arise.

Nullable foreign keys in SQL cause a number of problems and complexities. It's almost always better to decompose the table further rather than make a foreign key nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema isn't clear. Is it this...

```
Tables:
Puppies
Individuals
Corporations
```

or this...

```
Tables:
Puppies
Owners
```

I would suggest that the second scenario is a better design, allowing you to specify Owner.Type rather than having separate tables for each type of owner.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Table **Owner** and use **Owner's PK as FK to puppies**
Create 2 tables **Individual_Owner** and **Corporate_Owner** and use **Owner's PK as PK as well as FK to both of those**.

It is to clarify that for different types of owner you will use suck a PK column which is the mapped entry[FK] to Owner table

Place common elements of any type of owner to **Owner** table

Comment: KM is using Composition and I am using Realization. If you are using DataWareHouse then go for Composition[because it use star/snowflakes schema, so data access/size related optimization is not a hard issue] else go for Realization, which will reduce size of data but complex query may be a disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think what you want to achieve with the normalisation. Don't normalize just for sake of it. If you make your fk nullable then db won't help you keeping the data consistent.
Think:

- What if both fk's are null? (no owner?)
- What if both fk's has value? (two owners?)

On the other hand, solution suggested by @Puspendu has very same problems even though you don't have nullable foreign keys. In fact it complicates the case a bit further as it allows multiple owners and is more complicated to use.

So I would just got for the model you suggested, it is simple, does the job, and is easy to understand by you fellow programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Individual owners and corporate owners is a classic case of the gen-spec design pattern.

Search on "generalization specialization relational modeling".  You'll see some articles about how to set up three tables.  One for owners, one for individual owners, and one for corporate owners.  All three use the same key.  The PK in the specialized tables double as an FK, referencing the corresponding row in the owners table.

If you are used to object modeling, then the gen-spec pattern is familiar to you. It's handled by inheritance.  At first glance, the way relational modeling handles the same pattern may look dumb.  But it's really good.

The final question is whether you want the relationship between puppies and owners to be many-to-one or many-to many.  In the many-to-mnay case. you'll need a separate table to hold the puppies-owners relationship.  Otherwise, you can put an ownerID FK in the puppies table to link one or many puppies up to one owner.